# Gridview in a fragment populated with SQLite db - how to implement a callback to main activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-gridview

I have a MainActivity that extends FragmentActivity. There are two fragment. The first contains a GridView that is populated by a Cursor from an SQLite adapter class. I have assigned an onItemClick event to get the data of a clicked tile. Now I need to pass this data from the fragment to the parent activity so as to use it in the second fragment (according to Android development best practice). I have looked at several examples of implementing a callback and have tried to code it into my app, but I must be missing something very obvious because I cannot get it to work. Here is the first fragment (I have edited out the Callback bits with /* */ tags):

```
public class TimetableFragment extends Fragment {

private MobileClassDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private Cursor mTimetableCursor;
private ActionMode mActionMode;
/*    OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void OnItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnItemClickListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnItemClickListener");
    }
}
*/    
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timetable_fragment, container, false);

    GridView gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.timetable_grid);
    fillTimetable(gridView);

    return view;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void fillTimetable(GridView gridView) {
    mDbHelper = new MobileClassDbAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mDbHelper.open();
    // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
    mTimetableCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllTimetableActivities();
    // check the length of the cursor
    int count = mTimetableCursor.getCount();
    int days = 5;
    int lessons = 9;
    int test = days * lessons;
    if (count < test) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not filled with timetable  activities", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= lessons; j++) {
                String day = Integer.toString(i);
                String lesson = Integer.toString(j);
                if (mDbHelper.findTimetableActivity(day, lesson, null, null) == false) {
                    mDbHelper.createTimetableActivity(day, lesson, null, null, null);
                }
            }
        mTimetableCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllTimetableActivities();
        }
    }
    String[] from = new String[]{MobileClassDbAdapter.KEY_TIMETABLE_ACTIVITY,MobileClassDbAdapter.KEY_TIMETABLE_NOTE};

    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.timetable_text1,R.id.timetable_text2};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    final SimpleCursorAdapter timetable = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.timetable_card, mTimetableCursor, from, to);
    gridView.setAdapter(timetable);

    // create click listener
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            //JUST A TEST TO SEE IF THE ClickListener RETURNS THE CORRECT DATA
            Cursor item = (Cursor)timetable.getItem(position);
            String text = item.getString(item.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MobileClassDbAdapter.KEY_TIMETABLE_DAY))
                    + " " + item.getString(item.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MobileClassDbAdapter.KEY_TIMETABLE_LESSON))
                    + " (id: " + item.getString(item.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MobileClassDbAdapter.KEY_TIMETABLE_ID)) + ")";
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //END OF TEST...
/*              mListener.OnItemClick(parent, v, position, id);*/
        }
    });

}
}
```

Here is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

}
```

I have not included the second fragment, because I haven't started the coding for that yet - I first need to get the data from the fragment to the parent activity. I really need some advice on this...Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MainActivity` needs to implement the Interface of your Fragment.

Anyway you should handle your onItemClick within the Fragment and only inform the Activity about the result. In your case, you get the information about the AdapterView, the View and position/id of the item. But your Activitiy doesn't know about the GridView...

Handle your onClick inside of the Fragment and pass the Activity the desired result.

Therefore you should add an Interface like "itemClicked(InformationForActivity...)"

Try this:

```
public class TimetableFragment extends Fragment {
  ItemClickedListener mListener;

  public interface ItemClickedListener {
    public void onItemClicked(Item clickedItem);
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
     super.onAttach(activity);
     try {
        mListener = (CursorClickedListener ) activity;
     } catch (ClassCastException e) {
     throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() 
     + " must implement CursorClickedListener ");
     }
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   private void fillTimetable(GridView gridView) {
     ....
     Item item = ... ;// build your item
     mListener.onItemClick(item); //this informs the activity
   }
 }
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
                      implements TimetableFragment.ItemClickedListener {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  @Override
  public void ItemClickedListener (Item clickedItem){
  //inform the other fragment here!
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working up to the point where I need to build the item...can't figure that out yet (bit of a noob to this). Any idea how to build the item from a the cursor I have? I tried 'Item item = (Item)timetable.findItem(position)' but no luck...

Comment: You have to build it by yourselve. Depends on what attributes you have... You should use your own model - my "item" was just an example. Use your own class for this (something like "Hour" or "Timetable" for sure ;) ) Otherwise you can just return the String as a result, if you don't want to have a specific item ;)

Comment: Thanks a million. I built it in the meanwhile. You're a lifesaver!